# How to delete characters between two specified characters?

Tags: c

I want to delete characters between two specified characters. How can I implement this program? Is there any predefined function in c to do this?

Let's say I have :

```
C is an imperative (procedural) language.
blah blah blah /*this is a comment*/
```

I want my output to be something like:

```
C is an imperative language.
blah blah blah
```

I'm really sorry if this question is vague to understand.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define the range? Just by numbers?

Comment: It's always good to give an approximate requested function signature and a use-case.

Comment: If by "character range" you mean any part of text delimited by a fixed character or string, then no, there is no predefined function to do that.

Comment: @lkamp well, there *is* a `regexp` library...

Comment: so there's no function to do anything like, from ( to ) all characters will be deleted, right

Comment: @Eugene Sh Ok, there is a library for about everything somewhere. I was referring to the C standard library.

Comment: No. But you can use two functions for it.

Comment: @lkamp Well, GNU C provided library is not just *some* library. But yes, it is not standard C library.

Comment: is there any other way to do this without array??????

Comment: What array? Strings are array. You can't work with strings without arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void strdel_with_range(char *s, char *from, char *to){
    //code of validation here (omitted)
    memmove(from, to+1, strlen(to+1)+1);//strlen(to+1)(length of rest)+1(null-terminator)
}

int main(void){
    char data[][64] = {
        "C is an imperative (procedural) language.",
        "blah blah blah /*this is a comment*/"
    };
    char *start, *end;
    start = strchr(data[0], '(');
    end   = strchr(start, ')');
    strdel_with_range(data[0], start, end+1);//+1 : point to space after ')'

    start = strstr(data[1], "/*");
    end   = strstr(start, "*/");
    strdel_with_range(data[1], start, end+1);//+1 : point to '/' (end point to '*')
    puts(data[0]);//C is an imperative language.
    puts(data[1]);//blah blah blah
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function `remove_string_between_delimiters` which creates and return a new string which doesn't contain the part specified between the delimiters. The delimiter are strings as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * remove_string_between_delimiters(const char * str, size_t length, const char * first_delimiter , const char * second_delimiter) {

  char * first = strstr(str, first_delimiter);
  char * second = strstr(str, second_delimiter);
  char * new_string = NULL;
  size_t to_remove = 0, new_string_size = 0;
  size_t length_first_half = 0;
  size_t length_second_half = 0;


  if (  first == NULL || second == NULL ||  second - first < 0) {
    return NULL;
  }

  to_remove = second - first;

  new_string_size =  length - to_remove ;
  new_string = malloc(new_string_size);

  length_first_half = first-str;
  length_second_half = length - (second - str) - strlen(second_delimiter);


  memset(new_string, 0, new_string_size);
  memcpy(new_string, str, length_first_half);
  memcpy(new_string + length_first_half, second + strlen(second_delimiter), length_second_half);

  return new_string;
}

int main() {
  const char * test = "This is a test /* sdfsfs */";
  printf("%s\n", remove_string_between_delimiters( test, strlen(test), "/*", "*/" ));
}
```

Output:

```
This is a test
```

The delimiters can be anything.